# C++ no instance of function template

Tags: c++

This is what in my .h file, DbQuery class:

```
template<typename T>
void showResults(Query<T>::Keys& keys, std::ostream& out = std::cout)
{
    out << "\n  ";
    for (auto key : keys)
    {
        out << key << " ";
    }
}
```

This is what in my .cpp file:

```
bool testR6a()
{
    Utilities::title("Demonstrating Requirement #6a - query for value");
    DbP dbp;
    Query<std::string> query;
    Query<std::string>::Keys result = query.qKeys(dbp.db(), "a");
    showResults(query.qKeys(dbp.db(), "a"));
    return true;
}
```

I can't figure out what is the problem of my instance.
E0304: no instance of function template "DbQuery::showResults" matches the argument list
argument types are: 
(std::vector>)

Does anyone know?

I feel bad that I don't think I can make a simple example to compile. This is a small part of a big program and I don't know how to simplify it.
I don't know whether this image can make you understand better:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Without the signature of `query.qKeys(dbp.db(), "a")`, it's difficult to tell why the template substitution failed.

Comment: Provide a minimal, verifiable, example that compiles please.

Comment: Do you understand what the compiler is telling you?  `showResults()` expects a `std::vector` and quite likely `Query` is not that.

Comment: something was missed because of the system: the argument types are: (std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>>)

Comment: You have several compile errors listed there.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are relying on template argument deduction, while your function template is written in a way that doesn't support it. To put simply, the C++ standard defines several "non-deduced contexts". When a template parameter appears in one of those, it will not be deduced from a corresponding function argument. One of those contexts is on the left of scope resolution.

What I'm saying is that the compiler can't use `Query<T>::Keys& keys` to deduce `T`. That's why you are getting an error. You need to specify it explicitly:

```
showResults<std::string>(query.qKeys(dbp.db(), "a"));
```

---

Well, not really. There's still the issue of your code not being const correct. Unless `query.qKeys(...)` returns a non-const lvalue reference (I doubt it), your code is ill-formed on any standard conforming C++ compiler. MSVC allows binding non-const lvalue references to temporary objects as an extension. But it's not portable C++. You seem to be somewhat aware of that already, because you declare `result`. So the proper call when going with the approach above:

```
showResults(result);
```

Or alternatively, if your function doesn't need to ever modify the passed argument, is to accept by a const reference.

Comment: This is the part of C++ I always have a tough time choking down... kinda like trying to swallow feathers...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - It is quite unpalatable. But I sorta get why this restriction exists. Templates would be a truly chaotic mechanism otherwise.

Comment: I guess it something you just have to run up against 50 times before it sinks in... and I'm at about 3. (and I just read through the text for differing  resolutions within the past week -- I'll try adding more salt..)

Comment: Binding a temporary to non-const-ref is not a great idea either (though the OP's compiler will accept it)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Bah! I totally missed it. Though I think the OP was playing around and experimenting with their code before posting. There'e `result`, which is initialized exactly like the object the OP passes to the function.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of StoryTeller is good (the automatic deduction does not work). Theoretically, you can simplify your function into this. Now the deduction should happen automatically, so you do not need to give the compiler further hints.

```
template<typename T>
void showResults(T& keys, std::ostream& out = std::cout)
{
    out << "\n  ";
    for (auto key : keys)
    {
        out << key << " ";
    }
}
```